# Assuming X = A + B * C, where A & B are integers, C is irrational; Find A & B given X & C

Tags: algorithms, prime-factorization, mixed-integer-programming

I'm looking for an efficient algorithm which can solve this problem. Can I do better than with the following brute force algoritm in C++?

```
 pair<float, float> factorize(float value) {
        float min_err = 1.0f;
        float best_a = 0.0f, best_b = 0.0f;
        const float c = sqrt(3);

        for(int b = 0, max = value / c; b <= max; b++) {
            float t = value - c * b;

            float err = abs(t - round(t));
            if(err < min_err) {
                min_err = err;
                best_b = b;
                best_a = t;
            }
        }

        return {best_a, best_b};
    }
```

It simply looks through every possible combination of A & B and tries to find the best one.

Comment: If $A$ and $B$ are integers, they can be negative. Your algorithm doesn't account for that. Also, notice that $X-BC$ is an integer.

Comment: Not sure if it's good site for this stuff.

Comment: John: I ignored negative numbers to simplify the algorithm. As for X - BC being integer: yes, I was thinking about using the fractional part of X to somehow figure out B, but I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: If $C$ is irrational then $S(C)=\{n+mC\,|\,n,m\in \mathbb Z\}$ is dense in $\mathbb R$ so (unless you restrict $A,B$ in some way, e.g. making them positive) you can get arbitrarily close to $X$.

Comment: You want to find $B$ such that the fractional part of $BC$ equals the fractional part of $X$.

Comment: It seems that problem comes down to solving following equation for B:
$$
BC - \left \lfloor{BC}\right \rfloor = X - \left \lfloor{X}\right \rfloor 
$$

Comment: Do you need an exact answer or will A + B * C "really close" to X do? Note that using real arithmetic on a computer involves rounding and truncation errors.

Comment: It can be "really close". But, I would prefer the numbers to be as small as possible, for example:
if X was computed from 10 + 13 * sqrt(3), I would like to retrieve 10 and 13, not -133393, 147462 even if it the error is just as small.